# What is a Binary Standard

Tags: .net, com, middleware, dcom

I have been reading up COM, there is a mention of binary standard and how that makes language independence possible..
Whats binary standard actually?
In my mind, binary would mean machine level code, and if it means machine language how can that be independent at all?

Comment: From http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/38635/binary-standard: *A digital standard that has been specified at the lowest working level. Standards organizations often provide specifications that can be interpreted in different ways by vendors. **A binary standard implies that there is no possible interpretation,** because all the details (fields, variables, messages, etc.) have been defined at the bits and bytes level.*

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363(v=vs.85).aspx: *COM specifies an object model and programming requirements that enable COM objects (also called COM components, or sometimes simply objects) to interact with other objects. These objects can be within a single process, in other processes, and can even be on remote computers. They can be written in different languages, and they may be structurally quite dissimilar, **which is why COM is referred to as a binary standard;** a standard that applies after a program has been translated to binary machine code.*

Answer (score 5):

At its lowest level, COM is really only a binary-level standard that describes how two pieces of software can communicate. It's binary because it's **100% language independant**, it does not rely on source code, but only on a specific layout of structures in memory.

In my opinion, the best article to start with is [The COM Programmer's Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809982.aspx). This famous binary standard is explained at the beginning of the document that I quote here:

> The separation between service user and implementation is done by
>   indirect function calls. **A COM interface is nothing more than a named
>   table of function pointers** (methods), each of which has documented
>   behavior. The behavior is documented in terms of the interface
>   function's parameters and a model of the state within the object
>   instance. The description of the model within the instance will say no
>   more than is required to make the behavior of the other methods in the
>   interface understandable. **The table of functions is referred to as a
>   vtable**.
>
> **An interface is actually a pointer to a vtable**. The vtables are
>   usually shared by multiple instances, so the methods need a different
>   pointer to be able to find the object that the interface is attached
>   to. This is the interface pointer, and the vtable pointer is the only
>   thing that is accessible from it by clients of the interface. **By
>   design, this arrangement matches the virtual method-calling convention
>   of C++ classes, so a COM interface is binary-compatible with a C++
>   abstract class.**

And the schema that comes with it represents the binary standard layout in memory:

[image: COM VTABLE]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I dont understand the conversation though. There is one COM interface which the clients access, the COM interface points to a vtable? Is that right

Comment: An interface is a pointer. So, when we say "a COM client accesses an interface", it just means the client has a pointer in memory (represented by IFoo in the diagram), which points to a vtable (represented by IFooVtbl in the diagram).