# COM exe, C++, and MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, com, mingw-w64

Have abit of an odd question; I'm using a tool supplied by a large company that, for reasons I find somewhat baffling, uses a COM interface defined inside the exe itself. In the example code they provide, it looks alittle like this.

`#import "C:\\Path_To_Exe\\the.exe" rename_namespace ("exe_namespace");`

From what I understand, this is the way Microsoft Visual C++ compiler understands the COM and works with it, and I have had the example code working before (currently, it doesn't compile due to fiddling with my build environment).

My question is, is there a way to do the same with MinGW? The project I'm working on is mainly using that; we can use MSVC if required, but I'd ideally like to avoid using multiple compilers if possible. I'm currently using cmake to build with, but I'm willing to use a script to build the items that need the COM interface if needed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can redeclare all the necessary com interfaces. You should be able to do this even in plain C. Though it seems like doing this would be just a waste of time and you should use Visual Studio instead.

Comment: This is rather common for COM interfaces.  There is no reason why a MinGW  application cannot do the same. The advantage of using MSVC is that it provides code generation tools and the MIDL language which do help quite a bit.  A google search of "msdn register com interface" will provide you with details on how you can provide the functionality by hand.

Comment: [`#import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) implies that the file is a COM type library. You can inspect that via the old [COM/OLE viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx), and copy the interface code. As I remember of old working with COM/OLE via the g++ compiler is not very practical, though.

Comment: It's probably easier to write a simple DLL wrapping the interface. Compile the DLL with Visual Studio, use the DLL in your MinGW executable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "is there a way to do the same with MinGW" is no. #import is an *optional tool* that reads a COM [type library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221355.aspx) (embedded in a binary or not, the TLB corresponds in general to an .idl file, but that also is optional), and generates C/C++ code that's heavily dependent on .c and .h files that only Visual Studio provides.

The answer to "can I do COM with MinGW" is of course yes. I don't know much about MinGW and tools, but you can do COM with any compiler since COM is (just) a [binary standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325785/what-is-a-binary-standard).

If you get rid of #import, you'll have to change the code that uses what was generated (in the .TLH file resulting of the #import directive), COM helper, wrappers, etc. It can be a lot of work, but it's technically possible.

Now, in your context, I suppose it really depends how big the .exe's type library (the description of your COM classes, interfaces, etc.) is. Visual Studio's #import adds value, so you'll have to assess how much value it added for you.

If it's just one class, one interface for example, then it can be interesting to get rid of the #import. If the .exe already has .h files that correspond to the tlb, then you can use them, otherwise you'll have to redeclare some by yourself (and again, change the code that was using generated wrappers).

The sole fact that you ask the question makes me wonder if you have enough knowledge of COM (no offense :-) to get rid of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The COM subsystem is part of the Windows API, and you can access it using C calls to that API.

However there is a huge amount of boilerplate involved in this.  The compilers which support COM "out of the box" have written all this boilerplate, and packaged it up in some combination of compiled libraries,  template headers, and so on.

Another part of the usual suite of tools offered by these compilers is one that can read COM interface definitions out of an existing compiled object. COM objects usually contain a binary representation of their interface, for this reason.

There are a few ways you could proceed here in order to use g++; one option is following this broad outline:

- Use your MSVC installation to read the COM object and produce a C header file describing the interface.
- Pick out the enumerations and GUIDs from that header file.
- In g++, use the Windows API to invoke the object, using those enumerations and GUIDs.

If you want to author objects in g++ then there is a lot more work to do as you need to implement a bunch of things, but it is possible.

I have done this successfully in the past with g++ (as part of testing COM objects I'd developed).  Probably somebody *could* develop a nice open-source suite for using COM objects, or even for authoring, that does not depend on MSVC but I'm not aware of such a thing.

I would recommend reading the books by Don Box, they fill in a lot of gaps in understanding that you will have if you've only learned about COM by working with it and reading the internet.